# how to push android dialog further than top window border?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-dialog

I have a dialog `optionsDialog`and I want to push it over the top of window border so I'm trying this:

```
     WindowManager.LayoutParams params = optionsDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
     params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
     params.y = -1000;

     optionsDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
```

But it's not working. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dialog has a RelativeLAyout as root you can use this (if not adjust it to the view you have as root):

```
    RelativeLayout dialogWrapper = (RelativeLayout) optionsDialog.findViewById(R.id.your_dialog_root_view_id); //NOtice here goes id for root RelativeLayout or anyother root view

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, -1000, 0, 1000); //MArgins: left top right bottom
    dialogWrapper.setLayoutParams(params);
```